# VBA code to run against Microsoft Project Templates

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have to generate macros to be run in Microsoft project. 
I am not able to perform the calculations to get a result, even after a lot of research.

It is 14 quality checks for your IT project schedule. 
I am trying to perform the easiest one first that is Resource Check.

Resources Check identifies all the tasks that do not have resources (people or costs) assigned. A quality schedule has all resources assigned to tasks in the schedule.

- Green Flag = < 5% of tasks meeting any of the above logic.
- Red Flag = > 5% of tasks meeting any of the above logic.

How do I perform this?

Comment: Project has a macro recorder, why don't you use that to learn more about the Project's Object Model. Project is not a popular program like Excel or Word, so not few people know the object model of the top of their heads

Comment: You need to loop through the `Tasks` in the `ActiveProject` and count how many tasks don't have resources (e.g. `tsk.Assignments.Count = 0`). Remember, StackOverlow is not about someone else writing your code, it's about getting specific help when you're stuck. Try posting some code you've written and show where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Try googling Eversight for Microsoft Project - it's a free add on for project 2010 that allows you to set up your own quality check profiles, including your own RAG thresholds.